# How to get first string from NSArray

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsarray

I have this code:

```
    NSData * databuffer = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:databuffer encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];   //  convert databuffer to a string

    //  now, take user's input string and separate rows into array
    NSArray *tempArray =[dataString componentsSeparatedByString:@"#0D"];
```

My problem is that when I do the last statement, I get one array with the entire dataString, like this:

> tempString[0]: dealer_book_id    author  title   description price   status  first   signed  format  dj  publisher   date    place   edition isbn    condition   djcondition illustrator keywords    qty catalog1
>   9780874834796   "Forest, Heather"   Wisdom Tales from Around the World  "Little Rock, Arkansas, U.S.A.: August House Pub Inc, 1996.   New.  The fifty folktales and parables in this collection comprise ancient plots both poignant and comical. This anthology contains simple truths, and the promise that we can benefit from past generations' experience.By Heather Forest.   19.95   active  n   n   Soft cover  n   "Little Rock, Arkansas, U.S.A.: August House Pub Inc"   1996            874834791   New             1   New Book

The first string ends at "catalog1" and the next string starts immediately after that (there is a carriage return (0x0d) between strings.

For the life of me, I can't seem to split the input string (created in a spread sheet) to an array, where each string is a separate row in the array.

Can someone please show me how to do this correctly?  I have done Google and looked in SO, but found nothing.

Comment: I assume `#0D` is suposed to be the carriage return code but I've never seen that kind of escaping. Do you mean `\x0D` maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Unbelievable! changed it to \r and it works like a champ...